# CSS Transition - Reducing Width Is Bouncy - Get Rid of Bouncy Transitions

Tags: css

I am pretty new to CSS transitions with less understanding and practice of the concept. But somehow, I managed to get a transition on the logo of the [site](http://goo.gl/egMXwj). If you kindly take a look, you'll see that upon page scroll, the logo Image gets reduction in width with transition. But its sort of vibrating/bouncy. It should be smooth transition.

Here is the css

```
#header.sticky, #site-logo a img, #site-logo a{
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}

#header.sticky #site-logo a img, #header.sticky #site-logo a{
transition:all 1s ease-in-out 0s;
width:90%;
}
```

It would be nice if someone points out the mistake I am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Hit and Trial worked.
It was actually the "0.5s" and "1s" factor (transition duration) that was causing the logo to transit like its vibrating. This solved my problem

```
#header.sticky, #site-logo a img, #site-logo a{
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

#header.sticky #site-logo a img, #header.sticky #site-logo a{
 transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
 width:90%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While Im not seeing much 'bouncing' try to level out the easing using linear and only transition the property you want. i.e

```
 #header.sticky, #site-logo a img, #site-logo a{
        transition: width 500ms linear;
    }

    #header.sticky #site-logo a img, #header.sticky #site-logo a{
        transition:width 1000ms linear;
        width:90%;
    }
```

Also, you only want the transition property on the initial state. you don't need it on both, for example

```
#element{
    opacity:0.5;
    transition:opacity 200ms linear;
}

#element:hover{
    opacity:1;
}
```

You only need to add `transition` on the `#element`, and when the element is hovered it will transition to and from the new/default opacity. you don't need to add the `transition` property to both

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
   #header.sticky, #site-logo a img, #site-logo a{
      transition: width 0.3s linear 0s;
    }
    #header.sticky #site-logo a img, #header.sticky #site-logo a{
        transition: width 1s linear 0s;
        width:90%;
   }
```